# Math operators in Criteria queries

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Given the mapped hibernate class:

```
@Entity
public class MyTestClass {
  /* id and stuff */

  private Integer aValue;
  private Integer bValue;
}
```

you can do the following with HQL:

```
Query query 
  = getCurrentSession().createQuery("select aValue * bValue from MyTestClass");
List<Double> resultList = query.list;
```

and get the calculated result out.

Is it possible to do something similar to this with the Criteria API? I still haven't found a way to use math operations with the Criteria API. We have aggregate functions like sum, avg and so on, but not the basic math operators?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make a new property in your class that is this computed value.  Just specify the formula attribute for that property.  Then you can include this property in your Criteria.

```
<property name="product" formula="aValue*bValue" />
```

formula (optional): an SQL expression that defines the value for a computed property. Computed properties do not have a column mapping of their own.

Answer (score 1):

you can always add it as sql I think there was some sqlProjection/sqlRestriction method