# Hibernate - restricting sum of two properties

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I want to write a Criteria query, that will do something like this:

```
SELECT a, b FROM t WHERE a + b < 10
```

Is this possible using Criteria API?

Comment: [Refer this operations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747109/math-operators-in-criteria-queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes . You can use [Restrictions.sqlRestriction()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#sqlRestriction%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20org.hibernate.type.Type%5B%5D%29) to define the where clause using native SQL.

```
   Integer condition = 10;
   List<Object[]> results = (List<Object[]>)session.createCriteria(someTable.class)
            .add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("a + b < ?" , condition , StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER ))
            .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                   .add(Projections.property("a"))
                   .add(Projections.property("b"))
             )
            .list();
```

Important points :

- In  the return result , the value of column a is stored in
  `Object[0]` while b is stored in `Object [1]` .
- The input parameters in the [Restrictions.sqlRestriction()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#sqlRestriction%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20org.hibernate.type.Type%5B%5D%29) are the
  actual column name in the database while the input parameters in the
  `Projections.property()` are the java property name of the mapped
  Entity.

Comment: And what if I have aliases? Can I refer to them somehow?

Comment: What do you mean aliases? Can I know how is the SQL statement looks like if it has aliases?

Comment: I mean, if I have a complex criteria-based query with aliases. This restriction is just one of many, and I want to use other Criteria aliases here. I've solved my original problem by implementing a custom Criterion. Nevertheless, I'll accept your answer as a valid for my original question. Thanks!